# Hibernate Search mapping factory with spring bean injected

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, hibernate-search

I use [Hibernate Search programmatic api](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#hsearch-mapping-programmaticapi) and I have configurable boosting for each entity. Configuration can be read through service which I need to access in mapping factory. Is it possible to get this bean somehow inside SearchMappingFactory? The problem is that spring context is not fully created at the moment the search mapping needs beans from it.

```
 public class SearchMappingFactory{

   @Factory
   public SearchMapping getSearchMapping() {
       SearchMapping searchMapping = new SearchMapping();

       // here I need to read configuration using configurationService
       // ... define mapping ...

       return searchMapping;
   }
 }
```

Then I set this mapping in sessionFactory this way

```
 hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.search.model_mapping", SearchMappingFactory.class.getCanonicalName());
```

I could pass instance of SearchMappingFactory with autowired bean inside but SearchMappingBuilder.getProgrammaticMappingClass does not allow that...

Comment: Could you clarify your question and add more context/code? What do you mean with "Configuration can be read through service which I need to access in mapping factory". What configuration service are you referring to? "The problem is that application context is not fully created" - are you talking about the Spring application context?

Comment: Right, it's Spring context, basically I need to autowire spring bean inside SearchMappingFactory. In this case this bean is my configurationService where I read xml configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I made SearchMappingFactory a bean with autowired dependencies and passed searchMapping directly there:

```
 hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.search.model_mapping", searchMappingFactory.getSearchMapping());
```